# Backpropagation algorithm in neural network

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network

I have some troubles implementing backpropagation in neural network. This implementation is using ideas from slides of Andrew Ng's course on machine learning from Coursera (here is the link https://www.coursera.org/course/ml). I think that I have understood the algorithm, but there is some subtle error in the code.

I'm using a network with 1 input layer, 1 hidden layer and 1 output layer. They have 2 + 1, 2 + 1, 1 neurons respectively (+1 is for bias).
When I tried to implement logical AND and logical OR everything worked great, and network learned to give correct values. But then I tried to implement XNOR (a XNOR b = NOT (a XOR b)).

I used 4 examples:

- 0 0 1
- 0 1 0
- 1 0 0
- 1 1 1

But suddenly, on this function gradient doesn't go anywhere. In the beginning I initialize weights with random small numbers (from -0.01 to 0.01). The output is near 0.5. Then I am doing gradient descent. Output is still always near 0.5 on any input.

I want to know how to fix this problem.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// contains matrix and Vector classes.
// Vector is just like std::valarray, but is compatible with my matrix.
#include "matrix.hpp" 

size_t L;
std::vector< Vector<double> > layers;
std::vector< matrix<double> > theta;

struct Example
{
    Vector<double> x;
    Vector<double> y;
};

using TrainingSet = std::vector<Example>;

TrainingSet examples;

double g(double x)
{
    return 1 / (1 + exp(-x));
}

void forwardPropagate(Vector<double> x)
{
    for ( size_t i = 1; i < layers[0].size(); ++i )
        layers[0][i] = x[i - 1];

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < L - 1; ++i )
    {
        auto z = theta[i] * layers[i];
        for ( size_t j = 1; j < layers[i + 1].size(); ++j )
            layers[i + 1][j] = g(z[j - 1]);
    }
}

void backwardPropagate(Vector<double> y, std::vector< matrix<double> >& delta)
{
    auto err = layers.back().slice(1) - y;

    for ( int i = L - 2; i >= 0; --i )
    {   
        delta[i] += asMatrix(err) * asMatrix(layers[i]).transpose();

        auto gdz = layers[i] * (Vector<double>(layers[i].size(), 1.0) - layers[i]);
        auto tmp = theta[i].transpose() * err * gdz;
        err = tmp.slice(1);
    }
}

double costFunction(const TrainingSet& examples)
{
    double result = 0.0;

    for ( const auto& example : examples )
    {
        std::cout << layers.back()[1] << '\n';

        forwardPropagate(example.x);
        for ( size_t k = 1; k < layers.back().size(); ++k )
        {
            auto h = layers.back()[k];
            auto y = example.y[k - 1];
            result += y * log(h) + (1 - y) * log(1 - h);
        }
    }

    return (-result) / examples.size();
}

void computeGradient(std::vector< matrix<double> >& delta, const TrainingSet& examples)
{
    for ( auto& m : delta )
        m.fillWith(0);

    for ( auto example : examples )
    {
        forwardPropagate(example.x);
        backwardPropagate(example.y, delta);
    }

    for ( auto& m : delta )
        m /= examples.size();
}

void gradientDescentStep(const std::vector< matrix<double> >& gradient)
{
    const double alpha = 0.01;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < L - 1; ++i )
        theta[i] -= alpha / examples.size() * gradient[i];
}

double gradientDescent(const TrainingSet& examples)
{
    const double eps = 0.0000001;

    double prev, cur;
    cur = costFunction(examples);

    size_t iterations = 0;
    const size_t max_iterations = 200000000;

    std::vector< matrix<double> > delta;
    delta.reserve(L - 1);
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < L - 1; ++i )
        delta.emplace_back(theta[i].rows(), theta[i].cols());

    do
    {
        prev = cur;
        computeGradient(delta, examples);
        gradientDescentStep(delta);
        cur = costFunction(examples);

    } while ( fabs(cur - prev) >= eps && iterations++ < max_iterations );

    std::cout << "Made " << iterations << " iterations\n";

    return cur;
}

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin("input.txt");    
    std::istream& in = fin;    

    std::cout.sync_with_stdio(false);

    in >> L;
    std::vector<size_t> architecture(L);

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < L; ++i )
        in >> architecture[i];

    layers.reserve(L);
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < L; ++i )
    {
        layers.emplace_back(1 + architecture[i]);
        layers.back()[0] = 1;
    }

    const double eps = 0.01;    

    theta.reserve(L - 1);
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < L - 1; ++i )
    {
        theta.emplace_back(layers[i + 1].size() - 1, layers[i].size());
        theta[i].randomInitialize(eps);
    }

    size_t number_of_examples;
    in >> number_of_examples;

    examples.reserve(number_of_examples);
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < number_of_examples; ++i )
    {
        auto x = Vector<double>(architecture.front());
        auto y = Vector<double>(architecture.back());

        for ( size_t j = 0; j < architecture.front(); ++j )
            in >> x[j];

        for ( size_t j = 0; j < architecture.back(); ++j )
            in >> y[j];

        examples.emplace_back(Example{x, y});
    }

    for ( auto example : examples )
    {
        forwardPropagate(example.x);
        std::cout << layers.back()[1] << '\n';
    }

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < theta.size(); ++i )
        std::cout << "θ[" << i << "] = " << theta[i];

    gradientDescent(examples);

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < theta.size(); ++i )
        std::cout << "θ[" << i << "] = " << theta[i];

    std::cout << "\n\n\n";

    for ( auto example : examples )
    {
        forwardPropagate(example.x);
        std::cout << layers.back()[1] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand C++ well enough to read your code. Have you stepped through this with a debugger and monitored how the weights change? I expect the hidden layer will be learning the `AND` and `NAND` functions. Also, have you tried adding more training data, even if they are repeated examples?

Comment: @eigenchris I monitored how the weights change, actually, they change very little, about 10^(-6). Also if I set initial values to be in interval (-ε, ε) and ε = 0.5 then my gradient descent does about 2000 iterations. If I set ε = 0.01, then it doesn't do any iterations at all. I haven't tried more data even if they are repeated, but I'm about to do this right now. **Edit:** Just tried, nothing changes.

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest. I know Andrew Ng suggests implementing a gradient check function that takes the gradient numerically to verify that your gradient function is doing the right thing. If you have no other ideas it could be worth a try.

Comment: @eigenchris That is worth to try, and I will, but what if not?

Comment: You might try posting in Cross-Validated rather than Stackoverflow. That's the best forum for statistics and machine learning. I'm just not familiar enough with templates and linear algebra in C++ to follow what's going on

Comment: @eigenchris Thanks for your help! I'll think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have realized what's wrong. The problem is not in the code itself. The thing is that cost function on such network configuration with XOR has local minimum. So, I came there and was stuck.

Solution is to make a step in random direction until you made it out of local minimum. It allows you to get to the global minimum quite fast.

Answer (score 2):

Generally for random initialization weights are in the range of ~[-3, 3]. The initial greater amounts of error (by having a larger weights) helps "jump" the weights into converging to the proper areas. Yes the XOR problem has local minima but your network should easily be able to converge to the proper answer with only a few hidden nodes.

You shouldn't "need" to take steps out of local minima, it should easily converge to the correct optima. XOR problem with the network structure being [2,2,1] has such a small amount of weights that you could essentially "random initialization" your weights to the correct optima relatively quickly. (Because the search space is small)

*note / edit*  if your network only has 2 hidden nodes there is a good change it will get stuck at local minima. a network even the size of ~[2,7,1] should be able to converge without the random steps.